# RxJava2 range() метод не работает в Andoid

Tags: android, rxjava, rxjava2

Документация:

> "The Range operator emits a range of **sequential** integers, in order, where you select the start of the range and its length".

Насколько я понимаю, должно быть последовательное увеличение на 1.

Это тестировалось в onCreate() методе  в главном Activity:

```
Observable<Integer> obserable=Observable.range(1,100000)

Observer<Integer> observer=new Observer<Integer>(){
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d){}
    public void onNext(Integer i){
        Log.d("123","Value is "+i);
    }
    public void onError(Throwable e){}
    public void onComplete(Throwable e){
        Log.d("123","onComplete()");
    }
};
obserable.subscribe(observer);
```

Вывод такого формата, причем всегда разный:

```
Value is 99974
Value is 99987
Value is 99995
onComplete()
```

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле все работает именно так, как написано в документации. Попробуйте взять 2 число в параметре поменьше и посмотрите лог. Все будет прекрасно.

Comment: работает, проверялось так: создана коллекция, добавление по 1-му элементу, потом проверялось количество элементов, в итоге совпало, но почему тогда Log.d так отрабатывает? он не успевает печатать и просто поэтому не печатает некоторые значения?

Comment: @Marina94 лично у меня писало cледующее:
read: unexpected EOF!